# How do I know which one of them is not equal to the rest

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

I have the following 4 states:

$$|\psi_2\rangle = 0.6|0\rangle + 0.8i|1\rangle$$
$$|\psi_1\rangle = −0.6i|0\rangle + 0.8|1\rangle$$
$$|\psi_4⟩ = 0.6i|0\rangle + 0.8|1\rangle$$
$$|\psi_3⟩ = −0.6|0\rangle − 0.8i|1\rangle$$

Which one of them is not equal to the rest and how to calculate it? So far, I've always come to the conclusion that 1 and 4, 2 and 3 are equivalent, but my professor said that 3 are equal together. Where did I make a mistake? Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just addition to solution by Mark S. In general, if for two states holds $|\psi\rangle=k|\phi\rangle$, where $k$ is a complex number, then the states $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ are said to be equivalent in sense that they are physically indistinguishable.

To be precise $k$ is often expressed in exponential form $e^{i\varphi}$. Then the angle $\varphi$ is called global phase.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to QCSE.  This question clearly tests whether you know how states are related to each other up to a global phase.

$|\psi_1\rangle=-i|\psi_2\rangle$ (do you see why?), while $|\psi_3\rangle=-|\psi_2\rangle$.

$|\psi_4\rangle$ is the odd-one-out.

Comment: Ah Thank you very much for the help, now i understand it